# SQL Select distinct rows with duplicate values in one column and choose one row for each duplicate based on value in primary key field

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, subquery, primary-key

I have an SQL table with duplicate records on FacilityID.  FacilityKey is unique.  I need to select rows that have duplicates on FacilityID but I only want to show one record for each and I want to choose the one with the most recent (highest) FacilityKey.  Can anybody help me figure out how to write my query? I've tried everything I could think of and searched the internet for something similar to no avail. All I can find are examples of identifying the duplicate records.

Comment: Are FacilityID and FacilityKey only columns in the table?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this site and didn't realize anybody had answered right away.  There are more columns and I did want to select * columns.  The person below actually gave an example for that and it worked great!!  :-)  Thank you for reading/answering my post!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select FacilityID, max(FacilityKey)
from Facilities
group by FacilityID
having count(FacilityID)>1
```

And then if you want to get all of the fields, something like this:

```
select *
from facilities
    inner join (
        select FacilityID, max(FacilityKey) as maxkey
        from Facilities
        group by FacilityID
        having count(FacilityID)>1
      ) t on t.FacilityID = facilities.FacilityID and t.maxkey=facilities.FacilityKey
```

Comment: Oh bless your heart, you are an angel!!!!!!  That worked perfectly!!!!!  I have been struggling with this for a day and a half!!!!  Thank you!!!!!  :-)

Comment: Of course!  I would have eventually figured this out.  You saved me time!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select  
    FacilityKey , MAX(FacilityID)  AS FacilityID
    From YourTable 
    GROUP BY FacilityKey  
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: You've got FacilityKey and FacilityID the wrong way round for the problem as described. The other answer is correct.